# Cherry Framework Child Theme - blank custom page template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm using a child theme that uses Cherry Framework.

I would like a custom page template that is completely blank.

If I make a file called **"blank-template.php"** and put it **/wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/** with the following code.

```
<?php
/**
  Template Name: Blank Template

*/

?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

If I then make a new page in Wordpress, and select this template and load the page, I expect to see a blank page however I see a page that has my theme header and footer with the words "test" in middle, as per my file.

Am I missing a step to make a fully custom template that ignores my themes header and footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_header();` and `get_footer();` are missing.

```
<?php
/**
  Template Name: Blank Template

*/
?>
<html>
    <head>
     <?php get_header();?>
    </head>

    <body>
        test
    </body>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</html>
```

For more details : http://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-how-to-create-a-child-theme-based-on-cherry-framework.html